# How can I calculate the position of an element within a responsive parent container?

Tags: html, css, css-position, viewport

I have a div container with a responsive width and height when I start minimizing the page. It also has a min-width. I want add a floating action button that is 24px from the bottom and 24px from the right of the div container. I've tried making the container's position relative, while the button will have a position of fixed, but the button is still relative to the viewport.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible with fixed position?

Is there another way to do this, or possibly recalculate the position of the button based on the containers width?

```
<div class="container">
<button class="button" type="button">
    I want to be relative to my container and not the viewport
</button>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    min-height:500px;
    min-width: 1500px;
}

.button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 24px;
   right: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Use `position: absolute` for the button?

Answer (score 0):

Why not `position: absolute` on the button?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 24px;
  right: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button" type="button">
    I want to be relative to my container and not the viewport
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the desired effect, you should use `position: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`.

> MDN [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
> CSS property
> The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its *nearest positioned ancestor* (i.e., the nearest ancestor that is not `static`). Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning, with the exception that the element's containing block is the **initial** containing block established by the *viewport* [i.e., `body`]

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500px;
  min-width: 1500px;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 24px;
  right: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button" type="button">
    I want to be relative to my container and not the viewport
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answer already? Including MDN's link? Uh, you could add it in a comment already.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Well, the other answer was posted while I was composing this one, so I didn't see it until now. But to answer your question, the difference is my explanation (quoted resource).